# full width cuts off after zooming in

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a full accessible site, so for people that have bad eyesight, they might want to zoom in. When I zoom in to test, the full-width background gets cut off, and I have no idea why this is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
     <style>
      #upper-rowwide
      {
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
      }
      #content
      {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1400px;
        color: White;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="upper-rowwide">
    <div id="content">
        fwfw
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just zoom in on the page, and then scroll to the right, and you'll notice the bar is no longer 100% width, but has been cut off. The black bar is supposed to be a repeating background image, fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is more what you were wanting. Set the min-width of the #upper-rowwide to 1400px. See fiddle.

Also, you can set the min-width of #upper-rowwide to a greater amount to see the content being centered.

```
#upper-rowwide {
    background: #000;
    min-width: 1400px;
}
#upper-row {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1400px;
    color: White;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYLUV/3/

Comment: Hi @dwreck08 If I do that, then my content flies to the left when I zoom out - know what I mean? I have all my content horizontally centered, which won't be the case anymore with 100%

Comment: I'm not seeing what content is centered to begin with?  If it is text, add text-align center - see updated fiddle and code.

Comment: There is a ton of stuff: menu, images, etc, so  have a container - which I just renamed 'content' to give you a better idea

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks for taking the time to help me out, I appreciate it!